# Recommendations or comparisons on Indy's TidHTTPServer versus Delphi's TDSHTTPService

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy, datasnap

I need to implement a small, standalone web server that will be used to process REST API calls, using Delphi 2010.  There seem to be two easy choices available with Delphi 2010 out of the box: Indy's TidHTTPServer and Delphi's own TDSHTTPService.

I am familiar with Indy components and would probably use them without question; there is a lot of documentation on them and examples.  But I have no experience with DataSnap; TDSHTTPService seems to have very little documentation.

Any recommendations or comparisons between the two?

Comment: As the answer states, use DataSnap.  TDSHTTPService is part of DataSnap - and DataSnap is built on top of Indy.  So I guess I end up using both. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with datasnap, because it has built in support for the REST.

and there's a [white paper by Marco Cantu](http://www.embarcadero-info.com/in_action/radstudio/rest.html) describe it in good details with videos

Beside he's new Book ["Delphi 2010 Handbook"](http://www.marcocantu.com/dh2010/) has more details than the above white paper, and should be available soon as eBook.

Also Bob Swart has another white paper with videos for [DataSnap](http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/datasnap)

Comment: If you use DataSnap, you're also using INDY, because DataSnap is using INDY behind the scenes.  http://wings-of-wind.com/2009/08/19/rad-studio-2010-review-11-datasnap/

Comment: Right, but if he used indy directly, it will require much work for him to do the works that datasnap doing.